# Python shutil.ignore_patterns error

Tags: python, shutil, copytree

I'm trying to write a simple script to move files from one folder to another and filter unnecessary stuff out. I'm using the code below, but receiving an error

```
import shutil
import errno

def copy(src, dest):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns('*.mp4', '*.bak'))
    except OSError:
        if OSError.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
            shutil.copy(src, dest)
        else:
             print("Directory not copied. Error: %s" % OSError)

src = raw_input("Please enter a source: ")
dest = raw_input("Please enter a destination: ")

copy(src, dest)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/Users/XXX/PycharmProjects/Folders/Fold.py", line 29,
  in <module>
  copy(src, dest)   
File "/Users/XXX/PycharmProjects/Folders/Fold.py", line 17,
  in copy
  ignore_pat = shutil.ignore_patterns('*.mp4', '*.bak') 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ignore_patterns'
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `ignore_patterns` was apparently added in 2.6.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't realize my PyCharm was using 2.5.6!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python version is too old. From the [`shutil.ignore_patterns()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.ignore_patterns):

> *New in version 2.6.*

It is easy enough to replicate the method on older Python versions:

```
import fnmatch 

def ignore_patterns(*patterns):
    """Function that can be used as copytree() ignore parameter.

    Patterns is a sequence of glob-style patterns
    that are used to exclude files"""
    def _ignore_patterns(path, names):
        ignored_names = []
        for pattern in patterns:
            ignored_names.extend(fnmatch.filter(names, pattern))
        return set(ignored_names)
    return _ignore_patterns
```

This'll work on Python 2.4 and newer.

To simplify this down to your specific code:

```
def copy(src, dest):
    def ignore(path, names):
        ignored = set()
        for name in names:
            if name.endswith('.mp4') or name.endswith('.bak'):
                ignored.add(name)
        return ignored

    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest, ignore=ignore)
    except OSError:
        if OSError.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
            shutil.copy(src, dest)
        else:
             print("Directory not copied. Error: %s" % OSError)
```

This doesn't use `fnmatch` at all anymore (since you are only testing for specific extensions) and uses syntax compatible with older Python versions.